# vars in web.py layout template are all strings?

Tags: templates, layout, web.py

**code.py:**

```webctx
true_var = True
return render.edit(some)
```

**edit.html:**

```webctx
$var true_in_layout: $true_var
```

**layout.html:**

```webctx
$def with(ctx):
$if ctx.true_in_layout == True:
    $#pass
```

the question is if I want to judege , I have to use "True" in 
**layout.htm:**

```webctx
$if ctx.true_in_layout == 'True':
    "this is ok"
```

what's going on here ? If there's a satisfied way to user True in the layout template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also set var with this syntax:

```
$var true_in_layout=True
```

By the way, you can also do this for multiline strings:

```
$var header:
    <p>Header text line 1</p>
    <p>Header text line 2</p>
```

Comment: $var true_in_layout=True  and  $var true_in_layout: True  what the difference ?

Comment: The first example works like python statement while the second example captures everything after : as a string.